# php multi variable with more variables as string

Tags: php

Im trying to create a multi variable with other variables.
The problem i can´t use an array, because i would send the content over mail and there is allowed only strings.
The code (cant find the error):

```
$mailtext  = "Name".$name.$trenner."\n" 
              .= "Straße".$strase.$trenner."\n" 
              .= "Postleitzahl".$plz.$trenner."\n"
              .= "Ort".$ort.$trenner."\n"
              .= "Telefon".$telefon.$trenner."\n"
              .= "Mehrwertsteuer".$mwst.$trenner."\n"
              .= "IVA".$iva.$trenner."\n"
              .= "Produkt".$produkt.$trenner."\n"
              .= "Anmerkung".$text.$trenner."\n";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The concatenation operator is `.` not `.=`.

```
$mailtext  = "Name".$name.$trenner."\n" 
              . "Straße".$strase.$trenner."\n" 
              . "Postleitzahl".$plz.$trenner."\n"
              . "Ort".$ort.$trenner."\n"
              . "Telefon".$telefon.$trenner."\n"
              . "Mehrwertsteuer".$mwst.$trenner."\n"
              . "IVA".$iva.$trenner."\n"
              . "Produkt".$produkt.$trenner."\n"
              . "Anmerkung".$text.$trenner."\n";
```

`.=` is used to concatenate an existing variable.

```
$foo .= "Bar";
```

Is shorthand for:

```
$foo = $foo . "Bar";
```

Comment: Your right, thank you very much !